# UserAgent for Chrome using using selenium can be set to a specific sting like "test" for example?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, aerokube-moon

I have been asked to set an userAgent that the infrastructure team can grey/white list against when invoking/navigating to my automation websites.

I know that whatever browser is used it provides its user agent and if I want to override this value , I can set the related chrome options in my selenium code.

However I have 2 questions
**Q1)**, Can this userAgent be set as something like `'companyname'` to make it easily identifiable  and easy to whitelist

OR
it has to be the string `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36`

**Q2)**
If it has to be the string mentioned in OR then then what is the benefit of using that ( other than having the fixed value of useragent irrespective of chrome version)
Because browser also sends the UserAgent has a Header .

A explanation would be very helpful. I an timeboxed to do this.